# is it okay to change the value of parameter inside of method in Dart?

Tags: dart, coding-style

In Dart, it is allowed that change the value of parameter in method like this

```
void changeValue(int num) {
  num = 10;
}
```

I know that above code isn't occur Error, but `num = 10;` can't change actual value of argument.
(Because Dart is 'pass by value')

my questions are these..

1. Is it okay to change the value of parameter?
2. Is there any other reason or intention for Dart allowing developer can change value of parameter?

Comment: Parameters are just like any other local variables.  Sometimes re-assigning them is sensible and should be done (e.g. if you need to want to sanitize an argument and want to prevent the original, unsanitized version from being accidentally used).  Other times re-assigning would be gratuitous, and using a separate variable would be clearer.  Do whatever is best to improve readability and to prevent mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to change the local variable introduced by a function parameter, if you can and want to.

You can make it impossible by making the variable final:

```dart
void foo(final int value) {
  print(value); 
  value = value + 1; // COMPILATION ERROR: Value is `final`.
}
```

Most parameter variables *could* be final, but nobody bothers to write the `final`, because a mutable variable that nobody assigns to is just as good.
Especially if nobody *thinks* about assigning to them.

Cases where I would assign to the variable include:

- Computed default values

  ```dart
  int foo([int? value]) {
    value ??= computeDefault(); // (Cannot be a constant)
    // ...
  }
  ```
- Pre-processing, in case the parameter isn't *always* the actual value you wanted. (Could be argued that initialization is a special case of this.)

  ```dart
  T linkValue<T>(Link<T> node) {
    while (!node.hasValue) {
      node = node.next ?? (throw StateError("No values"));
    }
    // Do something more.
    return node.value;
  }
  ```
- Unwound recursion. If you convert your tail-recursive function to a loop,
  it's a waste of space to introduce a new variable.

  ```dart
  int treeSum(BinNode? node) {
    var result = 0;
    while (node != null) {
      result += treeSum(node.left); 
      result += node.value;
      node = node.right;
    }
    return result;
  }
  ```

  (Or maybe this is just laziness. Guilty.)

Your parameter variables are not final unless you want them to.
Reusing them is perfectly fine, as long as you don't change the *meaning* of the variable.
It's usually fine if the original value *can* reach all uses of the variable at least once. If not, then it may not be the same conceptual variable any more.